# The folder of WebApplication(XXX) does not contain a project to restore in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: .net-core, yeoman

Steps to reproduce

- Installed .NET core in Ubuntu16.04
- Used Yeomen to generate Web Application
- The following files /folders got generated

> appsettings.Development.json bower.json Controllers Program.cs README.md TestYoWebCoreApplication.csproj web.config appsettings.json bundleconfig.json global.json Properties Startup.cs Views wwwroot

Expected behavior

```
Dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

should restore and compile

Actual behavior

```
Dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

is not working

Error:

> "warn : The folder '/home/WebApplication' does not contain a project to restore.

Environment data

- dotnet --info output: dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2.1-003177

Answer (score 4):

Just update your dotnet version!
I fixed this doing:

```
$ sudo apt remove dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-1-003177 
$ sudo apt install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-rc4-004771
```

Then:

```
$ dotnet restore
```

works smoothly.
(To be exactly: I `rm -rf` mywebapp generated with yeoman and re-did it, but it should not change)

As today 19/02/2017